# Как правильно передать аргументы в функцию PHP

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM base");


function rowWhile($sql, $parameter){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo $result = $row .= $parameter;
    }

}

echo '<pre>';

echo rowWhile($sql, "['id_table']");
```

Пытаюсь передать условия перебора массива и его вывод, но ничего не получается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: base заменить на id_table? подучить php бы для начала, вы хоть понимаете что написали? - echo $result = $row .= $parameter; тут $row массив

Comment: Мне необходимо в получить строку вида echo $row['id_table']. Если явно ввести, то все работает отлично, а вот как сделать значение ['id_table'] динамическим? Чтобы я мог вызывать функцию и выводить разные значения из массива?

Comment: echo $result[$parameter]; а вызывать rowWhile($sql, "id_table");

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо. Целый день бился над этой проблемой. Но почему у меня не получалось сделать так: $row['$parameter']? Я добавлял кавычки... блиииинн понял. Всё. Спасибо. Как Ваш комментарий обозначить как решение?

Answer (score 0):

Вы недоучили синтаксис языка, операторы и выражения. Данная строка означает конкатекацию (сложение) строк: `$row .= $parameter`

В полном варианте - 
`$row = $row . $parameter`

В данном случае переменная `$row` - это ассоциативный массив, данные из которого выводятся так: `$row['id_table']`

С переменной так - `$row[$parameter]` (так как `$parameter = 'id_table'`)